# Twitter OAuth in console application

Tags: oauth, twitter, xauth

Is it possible to authorize twitter console application without visiting authentication web page?

I need it because I'm developing app that grab direct messages from our corporate twitter. This console application is scheduled on web server and is not driven by human.

Regards,
Alexey Zakharov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ask Twitter for an access token by supplying a username and password using [XAuth](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/xauth). This circumvents the need to redirect to OAuth webpages to get valid access without asking the user for username and password. Applications do need to ask permission from Twitter by email to be able to use this web service method. You should only use it to get a valid access token and then save that, and not persist the username/password in any way. It might be a suitable scenario for your console application?

Answer (score 1):

Check out TWURL. It's command-line CURL with Twitter OAuth built in: http://github.com/marcel/twurl

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to authorize any oAuth based API via Console.

if you have some sample code that your working with please share.

Also: http://p2p.wrox.com/content/articles/twitter-development-using-oauth-authenticate-against-twitter-api-walkthroughs