# How to Login twitter using Oauth from my android application?

Tags: android, twitter, oauth

I am making an application which is a Twitter client. This means it connects to Twitter with OAuth. I register my application to Twitter and got all my keys, but now I do not have an idea how to connect my application with twitter. I have done some code mention below. Please help me out..

```
Twitter twitter=new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
twitter.setOAuthConsumer(Consumer key, Consumer secret);
RequestToken requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken();
AccessToken accessToken=null;
Log.i("Acces Token",accessToken.getToken());     
Log.i("Acces Tokensec",accessToken.getTokenSecret());
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I got a few decent answers by just using the search function

Answer (score 8):

You have two choices. Number one is easier. Number two is more difficult.

Number one just continues where you left off.
After you get a `requestToken`, you will need to launch a `WebView` and point the URL at `requestToken.getAuthorizationURL()`. The user will then log in and choose whether or not to allow access to his/her account. Next, if he/she hit allow, an access code will be displayed the user must copy/paste in your your own application. You will use that key with `getOAuthAccessToken()` (I think, I used the difficult way described later) to get the auth token that you should store somewhere permanently. At this point you are authenticated.

Number two also continues where you left off minus one detail...
`twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(REDIRECT_URL)`.
That redirect_url must be set inside your twitter developer account first. Then follow the same steps as number one except that your webview needs to be customized. You need to use `setWebViewClient()` on your `WebView` and create a new class that extends `WebViewClient`. Inside the `WebViewClient`'s onPageStarted, check if the URL starts with your return url. And then get the oauth info:

```
String oauth_token = uri.getQueryParameter("oauth_token");
String oauth_verifier = uri.getQueryParameter("oauth_verifier");
```

Use the `oauth_verifier` with `twitter.getOAuthAccessToken()` to get your token.

Comment: good answer... lets say i go with first method... now i have two questions... how can i login/logout.... and the token which we saved permanently as you said in first method; next time when i open my application should i repeat the method or just use this saved token and how?

Comment: good answer! Please consider checking this as the right answer!!

Answer (score 1):

If the full OAuth web redirection is not convenient, you could try to use [Twitter's xAuth service method](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/xauth) to just convert a set of Twitter credentials to an OAuth access token (do that once, and save the token). Much easier on mobile applications, but you need to ask Twitter for permission to use xAuth by emailing api@twitter.com.

You could also check out [another question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652894/twitter-oauth-in-console-application/3656746#3656746) for more information on this.

If your problem is how to actually implement OAuth interactions, you might want to [check out OAuth library information on Twitter](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/oauth_libraries) and/or documentation on the library you are already using.