# Android- How to tweet using oAuth?

Tags: android, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Login twitter using Oauth from my android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675335/how-to-login-twitter-using-oauth-from-my-android-application)

I would like to know how can I tweet using oAuth in Android.

What should be the callback url??? Please help!!!

Comment: I guess  you need to provide more info on how you want to tweet, what language etc you want to use...

Answer (score 0):

There are few Java libraries on Twitter dev page that also support OAuth on Android. http://dev.twitter.com/pages/oauth_libraries#java

Comment: Yes but what would be a callback url for android???