# How to sign in to twitter using official twitter app

Tags: android, twitter

I have integrated twitter in my app. When i click a button it opens a login page in a web view. After signing in, a page asking for authorizing the app is displayed. I have seen in other apps when user has the official twitter app installed, it will use the twitter app to login like facebook does. But I cant find any articles online which uses the twitter app to login instead of entering the credentials using a webview. Is it possible ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675335/how-to-login-twitter-using-oauth-from-my-android-application

Comment: I have successfully connected the twitter already. My query is different. :)